# How to call method from AdminAuthServiceProvider in a laravel controller?

Tags: php, laravel

In AuthServiceProvider, I have the following line in boot function.

```
 Auth::provider('customer', function($app, array $config){
     return new CustomerAuthServiceProvider();
 });
```

I need to call a method from CustomerAuthServiceProvider in a controller. can I do it ?

Comment: @gulshan This is question is regarding use of Service Providers in controllers. Not Controller methods in other Controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`createUserProvider` method is accessible via `Illuminate\Auth\CreatesUserProviders` trait of `Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager`

You can get the instance of the `AuthManager` class via the `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth` Facade.

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
//...

class WhatController extends Controller {
   public function index()
   {
      $provider = Auth::createUserProvider('customer');
   }
}
```

**Note that** `customer` entry must be included in a `providers` array in `config/auth.php`

```php
providers' => [
  //...
  customer' => [
   'driver' => 'eloquent',
   'model' => App\WhatCustomer::class,
  ]
]
```

Comment: It says...  Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
Class 'Illuminate\Support\Facade\Auth' not found

Comment: It must be use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth; and It is working now, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Register your `CustomerAuthServiceProvider` in the providers list of `config/App.php`;
And then call it in your Controller using its alias `use CustomerAuth`, (You can use any alias) at the top of your controller. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/providers